# Completion date status of an event codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

[screenshot of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJHtn.png) [screenshot of db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9a7W.png) 
[2nd screenshot of db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4S1Zm.png)
I'm currently working on a function that displays the status of an event. I made a column in my db for the event status.

0 - cancelled, 1 - upcoming, 2 - on-going, 3- done.

I want to know how do i change the values of the status in the db by comparing the date of my event to the current date in codeigniter. Is it possible? if yes, how? If not, are there any ways to do the function?

[snippet of my db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BQl2.png)

Comment: You need to apply if conditions like if (event is going on) { then update status to ongoing } else if (event start date is greater than current date) { then update status to upcoming } and so on. Or if you are looking to update status by automatically for existing records, then you need to create a cron job for this who will change event status based on current date.

Comment: Please provide the code you used up till now to help understand the case better.

Comment: this is my model function. I was already to do the function but it keeps adding to my db the value of 3 in the eventStatus column.
public function dateStatus(){
   $dates = $this->input->post('eventDate');

     if(now() == $dates){
      $this->db->update('activity', array('eventStatus' => 
     }
     else if(now() < $dates){
      $this->db->update('activity', array('eventStatus' => 
     }
     else{
      $this->db->update('activity', array('eventStatus' 
     }
 }

@TamirKlein

Comment: @RohitMittal this is my model function when comparing dates from my db to the now() function but nothing changes in my db.

 $resulting = $query->result_array();
   foreach($resulting as $resultings){
     $date = $resultings['eventDate'];
     if(now() == $date ){
      $this->db->update('activity', array('eventStatus' => 2));
     }
     else if(now() < $date ){
      $this->db->update('activity', array('eventStatus' => 1));
     }
     else if(now() > $date ){
      $this->db->update('activity', array('eventStatus' => 3));
     }
    }

Comment: @EanJhonDeCastro can you share your database complete screen shot? and do you have any from and to field in your database as you need to get ongoing status as well?

Comment: @RohitMittal the screenshots are attached above. The eventStatus column in the 1st screenshot is a foreign key then i joined the two tables so that when eventStatus is 1, it will display the corresponding string value. but my problem is that whenever i add an event, it always insert a value of 3 in the eventStatus field.

Comment: @EanJhonDeCastro check my answer and you can contant to me over Skype: rohit.mittal54 if you still face any issue. I will be happy to assist you :)

Comment: @RohitMittal i contacted you in skype. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get current date using PHP syntax not `now()` and also need to update only single record. Check below code:

```
        $resulting = $query->result_array(); 
        $currentDateTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        foreach($resulting as $resultings){ 
            $date = $resultings['eventDate']; 
            $this->db->where('activityId', $resultings['activityId']);
            if (strtotime($currentDateTime) == strtotime($date)) { 
                 $this->db->update('activity', array('eventStatus' => 1));
            } else if (strtotime($currentDateTime) < strtotime($date)) { 
                 $this->db->update('activity', array('eventStatus' => 3));
            } else if (strtotime($currentDateTime) > strtotime($date)) { 
                 $this->db->update('activity', array('eventStatus' => 1));
            } 
        }
```

Hope it helps you.